# Modify how Drupal builds fields on a per form basis

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-forms

I want to change the way Drupal builds specific fields on a specific node edit/add form on my site. For example, when I use print drupal_render($form['textarea']); in my node--CONTENTTYPE--form.tpl.php file, I get the default Drupal render of the field widget. I want to modify the HTML markup of the field widget.

There are three ways I can think of that might solve this problem:

1. Using a forms equivalent of the theme_field() hook. This seems ideal, but after searching for the last few hours, I haven't found anything on this.
2. Building custom field widgets for every field type I'm using on that node. This is definitely not ideal and I have to believe there's an easy way to do this in Drupal from a theme point of view.
3. Manually build the HTML markup for the form and field in node--CONTENTTYPE--form.tpl.php with print $form['textarea']['und'][0]['title']; and the like.

Is there a hook in Drupal to do this, or must the code for every field I want to modify be manually generated?

Answer (score 0):

I think the hooks you are looking for are [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7). Refer to the [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) to know what you can set on the render array.